# "Sign in required" after I click "Make this app" in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

I have signed in to https://web.powerapps.com/environments/Default-b456ad3c-9a28-4fb9-af04-826556948104/home through my work account. But when I tried to create an app, I was asked to Sign in and it's just stuck in that step. When I click "More" in the window, I got:
Unable to obtain access token for resource 'https://service.powerapps.com/'. Error from ADAL.js: login_required (AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in.
My browser is Microsoft Edge and cookies are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be caused by blocking third party cookies.
Disable or reconfigure the browser settings, any adblockers, Privacy Badger, etc. and it should work correctly.